# Opening micro-controller package with vacuum pen

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-assembly

So I recently bought an STM32H7 chip to use for my undergrad final year project. The chip comes in a package with a label saying: "Fragile, vacuum pen must be used to remove this device". Unfortunately I have found no sources online on how exactly such a case should be opened. May someone help me out with a step by step solution on how exactly I go about opening such a package.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're probably worried about you bending the pins and then wanting to return it, assuming it's something like their 0.5mm pitch LQFP package.

Usually the outer packaging is either a tray or a cut piece of tape, and you either take the two rigid pieces apart or peel the adhesive top of the sprocketed tape.

Either way you have to move it to the board (which ideally has solder paste applied with a stencil), position it and reflow solder it, or perhaps use some more manual method. If you bend the leads it will be difficult to get them to line up again. A vacuum pen can be used to lift the chip out of the carrier and deposit it. The cheap ones have a small diaphragm type air pump and a hole that you put your finger over to make them suck, then when you remove  your finger the suction is greatly reduced. Final positioning can be done with fine tweezers and a microscope. I've done it just with tweezers on similar Atmel parts with 144 pins and 0.5mm pitch and it's not all that fussy.

But really, soldering something like an LQFP-100 should not be attempted unless your skills are fairly well developed on easier parts. It might have been better to start out with an eval board which has the fine pitch parts already attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vacuum pick-up tool like this:

http://www.techni-tool.com/330SO200?mkwid=sC3uBXpu9&crid=59637447381&mp_kw=&mp_mt=&pdv=c&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpOCHgtiu3AIVAWl-Ch0NqAQuEAQYBCABEgI7h_D_BwE

Assuming your chip is a LQFP package this advice concerns how fragile the leads are and how easily they can be bent. Using a vacuum pen allows the chip to lifted up out of the packaging directly, without 'scooping' it out from the side and potentially bending the leads.

That can be a problem as bent leads on these high pin-count, fine pitch devices are hard to straighten out and the chip won't quite sit flat on the PCB anymore.

In your case as this is a one-off prototype you don't strictly have to use a vacuum pen but you should be as cautious as possible in removing the chip and handling it afterward until it is soldered. You could use tweezers and very carefully lift it up by the corners which are beveled for example.